# What is the encoding format of dns file generated by DNSCMD command

Tags: dns, mdns

I have some Unicode Host A record names (like abcáxyz) in my DNS zone. When I use dnscmd /zoneexport   it creates a zone file. When I open this file in notepad or any text editor, it will show record name as abc\303\241xyz.  I want to read this file through program, I would like to know, which type of encoding dnscmd uses while writing to a file, to represent the such ( á ) characters as \303\241.

I tried to use following encode formats

iso-8859-1,
ISO-8859-15,
ISO-8859-9,
windows-1252,
windows-1254.
All are working for me, but I am not sure which one to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have posted this question on microsoft forum also and from there i got the answer

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverNIS/thread/35f954c9-2372-4175-9ef0-4fa4839fe408